# Criar um arquivo ".TXT" de configuração

Tags: c#, arquivo, txt

Meu problema é o seguinte, preciso fazer um arquivo configuravel para integrar ao meu projeto, segue o formato dele atualmente:

```
PRINTER = 127.0.0.12
PRINTER_PORT = 9100
```

Gostaria de formatar ele pra esse estilo:

```
[PRINTER]
PRINTER = 127.0.0.12
PRINTER_PORT = 9100
```

Atualmente estou utilizando o metódo de Dictionary pra obter os dados, tem alguma opção melhor? Já que se usar colchetes pra destaque no arquivo minha função não os lê.
Função:

```
var dic = File.ReadAllLines("config.txt")
          .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { '=' }))
          .ToDictionary(s => s[0].Trim(), s => s[1].Trim());
                VariaveisGlobais.DEFAULT_PRINTER = dic["PRINTER"];
                VariaveisGlobais.DEFAULT_PRINTER_PORT = dic["PRINTER_PORT"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o formato é semelhante ao do `.ini` pode experimentar algo pronto, procurar no nuget, exemplo: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ini-parser/, para instalar:

```
PM> Install-Package ini-parser -Version 2.5.2
```

A vantagem dessa lib especifica é que ela não depende do WindowsAPI, o que é vantajoso para portar seu código para outros ambientes.

Exemplo de uso:

Adicione as classes:

```
using IniParser;
using IniParser.Model;
```

Para carregar o arquivo:

```
var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
IniData data = parser.ReadFile("Configuration.ini");
```

Para ler como string:

```
 string useFullScreenStr = data["UI"]["fullscreen"];
```

No exemplo se o valor for `"true"` você pode fazer o parse assim:

```
bool useFullScreen = bool.Parse(useFullScreenStr);
```

Comment: Nem sabia que tinha algo pronto pra um parser, realmente ajudou!